# A function $f$ with $f\circ f \circ f \circ f=id$.

Tags: functions

For a fixed nonzero $c$, define a function $f: \mathbb{R}^*\times \mathbb{R}\times \mathbb{R}\times \mathbb{R}$ by letting:

$$f(x,y,z,t)=\left (\dfrac{c}{x},\dfrac{z}{x},-\dfrac{yc}{x},t-\dfrac{zy}{x} \right)$$

Then $$f\circ f(x,y,z,t)=f\left (\dfrac{c}{x},\dfrac{z}{x},-\dfrac{yc}{x},t-\dfrac{zy}{x} \right)=\left ( x,-y,-z,t \right )$$
and so $f^{(4)}$, composition of $f$ with itself four times, is the identity map. I want to know if there is a better way of seeing why this is true (rather than just computing it). Also I want to know if similarly one can obtain rational functions with other periods.

Comment: It is superfluous (not necessary) to use '\dfrac` in an equation that you are enclosing in 2-dollar-signs on each end. All you need for fractions enclosed as such is the regular ole `\frac'

Comment: and $c$ is not zero, right?

Comment: @dmtri, yes $c\neq 0$ so we have a self map of $\mathbb{R}^*\times \mathbb{R}\times \mathbb{R}\times \mathbb{R}$.

Answer (score 1):

Computing $f^{\circ 2} = f \circ f$ and then computing $f^{\circ 4} = f^{\circ 2} \circ f^{\circ 2}$ here seems to be the quickest method.

If you want a function of period $n$, you can construct one $f: \mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R^n$ by rotating the arguments:

$$f: (x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_{n-1},x_n) \mapsto (x_2,x_3,\ldots,x_n,x_1).$$

Then $f$ has period $n$. (Or *order* $n$ if you consider a group of functions with the operation being the composition.)